# Karate-Gatling shows a significant increase in response time than plain Gatling

Tags: karate

We have been using Karate to test our API services. We wanted to use karate-gatling for testing the performance of our API's. In this process, we have observed certain issues like:

- At a high load (100000 requestors) using karate-gatling we noticed that around 40 % of requests failed whereas with Gatling we had 0 % failures
- There has been an increase in the Mean Response time when using Karate-gatling compared to gatling
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Sc5.png)

Is there anything we need to additionally configure so as to achieve the proper response time. Could you please help ?

Comment: if the linked answer does not solve use the 1.0 RC: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide AND follow this process please: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue